# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel COM Dll usage

Tags: c#, .net

To use "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" COM dll in the .net project, which is the better approach.

1. Add dll reference from list of COM libraries to the project?
2. Copy the dll to bin/Release folder and then reference?

Comment: 2nd option seems better as it will be carried away whenever you will move the project to another PC

Comment: I do dislike exam questions that don't have the correct answer to choose from.  If you want to see that 2. does then use Build + Clean to see what happens to the file.  The correct answer is 3: set the Embed Interop Types property to True.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Approach is fine(dll will copy to your bin while build).
2. Don't Keep the DLL in Bin\Release, Instead keep it in custom folder (lib) and refer.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what @Jaya wrote, if you are targeting .NET 4.0 or later you can also select the referenced dll and set "Embed Interop Types" to true. This option (called NOPIA) will eliminate the need to deploy the Excel interop dll with your program.